# Distribute numbers across a range min max condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have difficultly finding a formula to this question.
I need the input number in C1 to distribute according to the min and max of each tire, the mock up result is in Column D. Please help, thank you[image]

Comment: One solution could be `=IF(C3>C$1,MAX(C$1-SUM(D$2:D2),0),C3-MROUND(B3,10))` in `D3`.

Comment: It work just perfect! Thank you so much! If you have a spare moment, can you help explain how the formula work that would be fantastic, thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, in `D3` you could try:

```
=IF(C3>C$1,MAX(C$1-SUM(D$2:D2),0),C3-MROUND(B3,10))
```

This `IF` statement will check if the adjacent cell will exceed the input in `C1`. If so it will `SUM` all values up to that point and extract that from the input. Because that can happen in cells further down the line too I used `MAX` to round to zero in those cells. If the statement returns `FALSE` however I used `MROUND` to round `B3` to nearest multiple of ten.

You could use the evaluate formula function in Excel itself to step through the formula to see what exactly it's doing too.

Comment: Thank you so much!